# XML Serializer, Port from MS to Mono, Order

Tags: c#, xml, mono, serialization

Circumstances made it necessary to run a .NET 3.5 application on Mono. The application does not use special libraries, but relies heavily on the XML Serializer to load a complex model.

Concrete I have the following situation, an XML statement like:

```
<compare-clause>
    <first-element />
    <second-element />
</compare-clause>
```

While first-element and second-element can be several different types, the order is important, as it defines which is the left and which the right operand. This works always fine on MS, but on Mono (with some elements) there is very strange behaviour. Mono ignores assigning the first property, assigns first-element to the second property on the target object, and leaves out the XML second-element completely.

The XML annotation on the class looks like this:

```
[XmlElement("first-element"), Type=typeof(FirstElementType), Order=1]
[XmlElement("second-element"), Type=typeof(SecondElementType), Order=1]
public ElementBase Left { ... }

[XmlElement("first-element"), Type=typeof(FirstElementType), Order=2]
[XmlElement("second-element"), Type=typeof(SecondElementType), Order=2]
public ElementBase Right { ... }
```

As I said, it does not work under some circumstances, sometimes swapping the order helps, although all types have the same structure and the annotation on both properties is the same, except for Order=1,2. This has always worked on MS .NET. Maybe it has something to do, if first-element comes before second-element on the annotation, although this should be completely unrelated according to general attribute specification (order does not matter).

Maybe this is still a bug with Mono XML Serialzer or I have misused it and it just works on MS. Nevertheless, I had to use the latest version of the XML Serializer (January 2013) in order to get the application working at all!

I would be grateful for hints on this.
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have carefully read the MS .NET Framework documentation again. Seems multiple notation of XMLElementAttribute is only considered an official option for collection-based properties. However, it is misleading that no proper error message is generated when creating the serializer then (both on MS and Mono).

I have made a workaround now for deserializing multiple types by adding an object[] property to the object, and setting XMLIgnore on the official properties of the model. That way, I can also distinguish between several types of elements, even if there is only one element expected.

To make things further clear, to those interested: I needed to deserialize a couple of object types, which are always identified through their element name, on different places within the document hierarchy. However, scalar polymorphic properties seem to serialize/deserialize only with the name specified on the property, and not on the type. That means type discrimination is only based on an attribute (xsi:type) and not on element name.

I have already researched for alternative XML serializer libraries. Although there are a few options with significant improvements, neither seems to be completely flexible or completed, especially in terms of class hierarchies.

Comment: Mono should work in the same way, please file a bug in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ with a minimal self-contained testcase